# Do I need an Apex Class or just a Trigger in order to update a lookup field in Salesforce?

Tags: class, triggers, salesforce, apex

I am working out of a sandbox and I am trying to automatically update the Vendor_Rep__c(Lookup Field) under the custom object Member_Vendor_del__c. Would like for it to update the Vendor Rep when a Member Vendor record is created or edited.

I have created visualforce page, which i am starting to believe that i no longer need to acheive what i need.

Also, with some help, i have created the following code for an Apex Class:

```
public class contactsearch {

public List<Contact>searchContact(string ContactType, string MemberState, String VendorID)
{
  return [Select Name From Contact
          Where Contact_Type__c = 'Vendor Rep' AND States__c = :MemberState AND Contact_Vendor_ID__c = :VendorID limit 1];

    }
}
```

Also, after reading several questions already posted, a few Apex Developer Guide articles, and watching a few tutorial videos, i created the trigger below. (Im not sure i even need the class in order to achieve what i need)

```
trigger VendorRepUpdateTrigger on Member_Vendor_del__c (before insert, before update) {

 for (Member_Vendor_del__c u : trigger.new){
     if (u.Vendor_Rep__c == null){

        u.Vendor_Rep__c = [Select Name
                            From Contact
                            Where Contact_Type__c = 'Vendor Rep' AND States__c = :member_vendor_del__c.Member_State__c AND Contact_Vendor_ID__c = :member_vendor_del__c.Vendor_ID__c limit 1];

      }
   }
}
```

I keep getting the error message below for line 6 in my trigger

"Invalid bind expression type of Schema.SObjectField for column of type String"

What can i do to get passed this error and get this trigger over into production and working 100%? Do i even need the Apex Class?

Answer (score 0):

To update the Vendor Rep when a Member Vendor record is created or edited you have to go with Trigger.

Some code changes are required to solve this issue. The reason of error message is you are trying to update a lookup field to a String("Name" field) instead of ID.

On your own code if you make the following changes I think issue will be resolved.

```
 trigger VendorRepUpdateTrigger on Member_Vendor_del__c (before insert, before update) {
     for (Member_Vendor_del__c u : trigger.new){
         if (u.Vendor_Rep__c == null){

             u.Vendor_Rep__c = [Select Id
                                From Contact
                                Where Contact_Type__c = 'Vendor Rep' AND
                                States__c = :u.Member_State__c AND 
                                Contact_Vendor_ID__c = :u.Vendor_ID__c limit 1];

           }
      }
  }
```

But the code is not bulkify code. To make your code bulkify do the SOQL query outside of for loop use that SOQL result inside the for loop.

Comment: I believe i have tried to use Id in instead of Name before but i will give it a shot. 

Also im not familiar with "bulkify". I can definitely move the SOQL query to just before the last closing curly bracket. Is there anything special that i would need to do to add the SOQL result inside the for loop?

Comment: I have made another change in your code and I believe that is the actual issue. Field binding is done using the sObject at where condition of SOQL query. I have used "u.Member_State__c" and "u.Vendor_ID__c" instead of "member_vendor_del__c.Member_State__c" and  "member_vendor_del__c.Vendor_ID__c .   Please try with the above code and keep here posting.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but now getting the below error message for line 5:

Illegal assignment from List<Contact> to Id

Comment: I added .Id at the end of the SOQL query. This eliminated the error.

trigger VendorRepUpdateTrigger on Member_Vendor_del__c (before insert, before update) {
for (Member_Vendor_del__c u : trigger.new){
     if (u.Vendor_Rep__c == null){

        u.Vendor_Rep__c = [Select Id,Name
                            From Contact
                            Where Contact_Type__c = 'Vendor Rep' 
                                  AND States__c = :u.Member_State__c 
                                  AND Contact_Vendor_ID__c = :u.Vendor_ID__c limit 1].Id;
  }
 }
}